# Top homology of a manifold with boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

As stated in the title, my question is the following:

Let $M$ be a compact orientable manifold with boundary $\partial M$. Is it true that $H_n(M;\mathbb{R})$ is always zero?

In the trivial case for compact surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, filling up the interior always gives something homotopically equivalent to an object of lesser dimension. However, I don't see a way of using this method for the general case. Manipulation with Stokes theorem doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your manifold is triangulated then if you want to find an $n$-cycle $c$, it is a linear combination of the $n$-simplices $\sigma_i$, $c=\sum a_i \sigma_i$. As in the case of a closed manifold, $\partial c=0$ implies that $a_i$'s are all equal. But it you have a boundary, you also get that $a_i=0$ for every $\sigma_i$ which is at the boundary. (I suppose that $M$ is connected, otherwise one needs to consider every component separately)

Comment: That's a very short proof!

Answer (score 5):

I just found out this is a simple application of Lefschetz Duality. (See Hatcher, Chap. 3 Sec.3 p.254 as a special case of theorem 3.43) By this duality,  $H_n(M)=H^0(M,\partial M)=0$.

Comment: I don't understand why this cohomology is equal to 0. Wouldn't it just be spanned by a constant function? How does relative cohomology take care of this?

Comment: @Espace'etale [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604044/top-homology-of-an-oriented-compact-connected-smooth-manifold-with-boundary) could help