# Cohomology with compact support of $T^2-\{p\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $X=T^2-\{p\}$ be the torus with one point removed. Since ${p}$ is closed in $T^2$, $X=T^{2}-\{p\}$ is open. In Hausdorff spaces compact subsets are closed, so $X$ is not compact.

> I was wondering how to compute the de Rham cohomology with compact supports of $X$.

It's not the same as the standard de Rham cohomology. As $X$ is orientable and connected, $H^2_c(X)=\mathbb R$, but I am struggling with $H^0_c$ and $H^1_c$.

Comment: Worth noting that $T^2 - \{p\}$ is open is only an argument that it is not closed given that $T^2 - \{p\}$ is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Poincaré duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_duality)
$$H_c^k \simeq H_{2-k}$$
you can reduce the computation to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2841784/how-to-compute-the-homology-groups-of-a-torus-with-n-points-removed).

Comment: Since $M=T^2-\{p\}$ is oriented one could also use the duality $H^k(M)=(H^{n-k}_c(M))^*$. So $H^{2}_c(M)=\mathbb{R}^*$ , $H^{1}_c(M)={\mathbb{R}^{2}}^{*}$ and $H^{0}_c(M)=0^*$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, this works as well.