# What is $S^1 \times S^3$ with an open disk removed?

Tags: differential-topology

I am trying to calculate the de Rham cohomology of the connected sum of $S^1 \times S^3$ with $\mathbb CP^2$. But I have trouble in figuring out what is $S^1 \times S^3$ with a disk removed. If I have that figured out, I can proceed using Mayer Vietoris, since $\mathbb CP^2$ with a disk removed is simply $\mathbb CP^1$.

Comment: Do you know what $S^1\times S^1$ with a disc removed is?

Comment: Yes, that deformation retracts to its boundary which is a torus.

Comment: No, $S^1\times S^1$ is a torus, it deformation retracts onto $S^1\vee S^1$.

Comment: Sorry, I was thing of the wedge sum of two circles but put in the wrong words...

Comment: OK, we're in agreement. So now, what do you think happens for $S^1\times S^3$?

Comment: They way I think about $S^1 \times S^1$ is to use its polygon representation. I am not sure how I can apply that to this case.

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3239759/90543) and my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3239775/90543) may be useful to you. The trick discussed there is to apply Mayer-Vietoris to the interior of the punctured manifold and to an open ball slightly larger than the one you are removing.