# The quotient map and isomorphism of cohomology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

Let $X$ be a closed $n$-manifold, $B$ an open $n$-disc in $M$.
Suppose $p:X\rightarrow X/(X-B)$ is a quotient map. Notice that $X/(X-B)$ is homeomorphic to  the sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$.

My question is whether the quotient map induces an isomorphism mapping $H^n(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ to $H^n(X/(X-B);\mathbb{Z}_2)$? Maybe it is known. But I can not find it in the literature.
If it is easy, can somebody show it to me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map of pairs $(X,X-B)\to(S^n,*)$ with $S^n=X/(X-B)$ and $*$ the point resulting from collapsing $X-B$, and the diagram you get from it in the long exact sequences for cohomology. The map $H^n(S^n,*)\to H^n(S^n)$ is an isomorphism, and so is $H^n(S^n,*)\to H^n(X,X-B)$, so by the commutativity of one of the sqaures in the diagram you want to know if $H^n(X,X-B)\to H^n(X)$ is an isomorphism. Is it?

Comment: In fact, I don't know why $H^n(S^n,∗)\rightarrow H^n(X,X−B)$ and $H^n(X,X−B)\rightarrow H^n(X)$ are isomorphisms. Can you show it  to me?

Comment: The first one you can get using excision and a little work. The second one, by using orientations and their properties.

Comment: Thanks. I think the first one also depends on the fact that $X-B$ is a deformation retract of a open subspace of $X$. Since I use the coefficient $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the second one follow from $H^n(X\setminus B)=0$, which I don't know why.

Comment: I did not say that the 1st one depends *only* on excision: what you mention is the little work I referred to, but the basic fact is that you can use excision to see that the relative groups involved do not depend much on what's inside of the X-B. As I daid, the 2nd one you can get by shoing that you can extend orientations to the whole of B; see the treatment of orientability on manifolds in the book by Greenberg and Harper.

Comment: OK, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $X\setminus B$ deformation retracts onto a lower dimensional subspace (assuming $X$ is connected) and so in particular $H^n(X\setminus B)=0$. Consider the long exact sequence in cohomology of the pair $(X,X\setminus B)$ given by $$\ldots\to H^n(X/(X\setminus B))\to H^n(X)\to H^n(X\setminus B)\to 0\to \ldots$$

As $H^n(X\setminus B)=0$ we can conclude that $q^*\colon H^n(X/(X\setminus B))\to H^n(X)$ is surjective and so also an isomorphism as $H^n(X)$ and $H^n(S^n)$ both have rank $1$.

Comment: The claim that the complement of $B$ deformation retracts onto a lower dimensional subspace is somewhat nontrivial, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez You're right. In fact I would probably use a homology argument to prove that. I guess that makes the above argument a little circular...

Comment: Where is the fact "$X\setminus B$ deformation retracts onto a lower dimensional subspace" come from?

Comment: @LewisZhang, as we observed in the comments above yours, that fact is in fact probably more difficult than the one you want to prove.

Comment: @LewisZhang as Mariano points out, proving $H^n(X\setminus B)=0$ is at least as difficult, either by having to prove $X\setminus B$ deformation retracts to a lower dimension, or by considering a relative LES in cohomology for the pair $(X\setminus B,\partial B)$ which would then just push the problem back another step. In the orientable case you can use for instance the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481850/top-cohomology-of-a-manifold-with-boundary), but I would suggest awarding the accepted answer to a more complete one than mine.

Comment: I'll try to fix this argument for the general case, but if I can't I'll delete this answer.